# Python - How to use underlying object's constructor as class method?

Tags: python

Please forgive the bad title - I had a hard time trying to think of a concise way to explain this.

I have a Python class that will have some underlying objects of other classes. I want to be able to create these underlying objects via a method of the original object. Let me try to explain better with an example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bars = []

    def Bar(self, a, b, c):
        self.bars.append(Bar(a, b, c))

class Bar:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
```

I would use the above as such:

```
f = Foo()
f.Bar(1, 2, 3)
```

So this works how I want but is kind of crappy with respect to maintenance. Is there a nice "Pythonic" way to do this that would make maintaining this easy? For instance, let's say I changed the constructor of `Bar` to:

```
__init__(self, a, b, c, d):
```

would there be a way to define all of this so I don't have to update the argument list in 3 places?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, no problem: Just pass [*args and **kwargs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) on to `Bar`:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bars = []

    def append_bar(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.bars.append(Bar(*args, **kwargs))

class Bar:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d

f=Foo()
f.append_bar(1,2,3,4)
```

PS. I changed the name of the method to `append_bar` because the [usual convention](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) in Python is to use lowercase names for methods, and I think methods whose names are verbs help describe what the method does.